# Can't upload large images

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload, resize

I'm writing php based image gallery. For the project I'm using CodeIgniter framework.
The sers can upload up to 5 images.

When a small images (800px in width) are uploaded it works. The problem comes when user try to upload 5 images each of them about 2mb and > 3200px in width.

In this case the images are not uploaded and $_POST is empty.

Here is what I did so far but unfortunately didn't help

I changed the default values in php.ini with this

```
max_execution_time = 180
max_input_time = 160 
emory_limit = 228M
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Check `MAX_POST_SIZE`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at:

- `upload_max_filesize = 10M`
- `post_max_size = 10M`

Answer (score 1):

You also permuted few letters in the name of variable:

```
emory_limit = 228M
```

It should be memory_limit.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick google, which I'm sure you could have done, I found [this website](http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/) with all the details you need.

The main indication is to add:

- php_value upload_max_filesize 10M - The maximum file size that can be uploaded.
- php_value post_max_size 10M - The maximum amount of post data allowed by PHP.
- php_value max_input_time 300 - The amount of time a script can run before being terminated.
- php_value max_execution_time 300 - The amount of time before a timeout that the site should upload a file.